# Can't find option in Google Cloud Run to add created Secrets to Variables - documentation is misleading

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

I want to add a secret to access my Mongo Atlas databases via my Cloud Run Managed application.
I followed this guide: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/using-secrets?hl=en

It described to first create the secrets - I did that

[image]

Then I have to add the secrets to my Cloud Run Service. However I can't find the option to do so. I only see the option to create "Environment Variables".

**This is what I expect to find when following the documentation**

[image]

**But I can only see this**

[image]

Do I miss to configure something to "activate" secrets beforehand for my Cloud Run Service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the note on the top of that page:

> Important: This feature is not available for Cloud Run (fully managed).